# long-short-sc format not working with custom glsabbrvscfont

Tags: small-caps, glossaries-extra

I have used the below code for a year or two now but suddenly it stopped working. I suspect since my last upgrade of TeXlive packages (which I haven't done in ages) so I suspsect something changed in the last few versions of `glossaries-extra`.

When I redefine `\glsabbrvscfont` to use `\SC` the abbreviation in parenthesis is not displayed. When I remove that line, thus using the original definition of `\glsabbrvscfont`, it works, though it shows the abbreviation in uppercase (obviously).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[abbreviations,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}
\newcommand{\SC}[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}
\renewcommand*{\glsabbrvscfont}[1]{\SC{#1}}
\makeglossaries
\newabbreviation{ARP}{ARP}{Address Resolution Protocol}
\begin{document}
Hello, world! This is the \acf{ARP} speaking\ldots
\end{document}
```

Now, the easy fix would be to redefine all my abbreviations, e.g.

```
\newabbreviation{ARP}{arp}{Address Resolution Protocol}
```

but I do not wish to do this as I might want to switch to a different format (e.g. long-short) later and then I would have to change them all back to being uppercase.

So, my question is, what changed in the package and how can I change it back to make my code work again?

**Edit:** when using the long-short-sc format, `latexmk` cannot complete compilation and I get the following message:

```
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
Latexmk: All targets (manual-student.pdf) are up-to-date
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'manual-student':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes
```